# Creating and applying a patch file?

Tags: c#, patch

Ok so I've done a little research on the subject, but I've only found a way to create a patch in c.

`diff -aru oldFile newFile 2>&1 | tee Patch.GBP`

Now would this work for c#? Also I want to make the patches name have the current date/time. That code isn't too hard, but I don't know how to read the date/time. If I know that I can make the rest of the code myself.

And final question. How would I apply the patch? I can set it up so that the user opens the patch in a open dialog, but Im new to patches so I'm not sure as to how to get the patch to apply.

Thanks!

Edit: .GBP will be my own patch file name, nothing special to it though.:P